# C++ MySQL++ Delete query statement brain killer question

Tags: c++, mysql++

I'm relatively new to the MySQL++ connector in C++, and have an really annoying issue with it already!

I've managed to get stored procedures working, however i'm having issues with the delete statements.  I've looked high and low and have found no documentation with examples.

First I thought maybe the code needs to free the query/connection results after calling the stored procedure, but of course MySQL++ doesn't have a free_result method... or does it?

Anyways, here's what I've got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include "RepositoryQueue.h"

using namespace boost;
using namespace mysqlpp;

class RepositoryChecker
{
private:
    bool _isRunning;
Connection _con;
public:
RepositoryChecker()
{
    try
    {
        this->_con = Connection(false);
        this->_con.set_option(new MultiStatementsOption(true));
        this->_con.set_option(new ReconnectOption(true));
        this->_con.connect("**", "***", "***", "***");

        this->ChangeRunningState(true);
    }
    catch(const Exception& e)
    {
        this->ChangeRunningState(false);
    }
}
/**
* Thread method which runs and creates the repositories
*/
void CheckRepositoryQueues()
{
    //while(this->IsRunning())
    //{
        std::queue<RepositoryQueue> queues = this->GetQueue();

        if(queues.size() > 0)
        {
            while(!queues.empty())
            {
                RepositoryQueue &q = queues.front();
                char cmd[256];
                sprintf(cmd, "svnadmin create /home/svn/%s/%s/%s", q.GetPublicStatus().c_str(),
                    q.GetUsername().c_str(), q.GetRepositoryName().c_str());
                    if(this->DeleteQueuedRepository(q.GetQueueId()))
                    {
                        printf("query deleted?\n");
                    }
                    printf("Repository created!\n");
                queues.pop();
            }
        }
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
    //}
}
protected:
/**
* Gets the latest queue of repositories from the database
* and returns them inside a cool queue defined with the 
* RepositoryQueue class.
*/
std::queue<RepositoryQueue> GetQueue()
{
    std::queue<RepositoryQueue> queues;

    Query query = this->_con.query("CALL sp_GetRepositoryQueue();");
    StoreQueryResult result = query.store();
    RepositoryQueue rQ;

    if(result.num_rows() > 0)
    {
        for(unsigned int i = 0;i < result.num_rows(); ++i)
        {
            rQ = RepositoryQueue((unsigned int)result[i][0],
                                (unsigned int)result[i][1],
                                (String)result[i][2],
                                (String)result[i][3],
                                (String)result[i][4],
                                (bool)result[i][5]);
            queues.push(rQ);
        }
    }

    return queues;
}
/**
* Allows the thread to be shut off.
*/
void ChangeRunningState(bool isRunning)
{
    this->_isRunning = isRunning;
}
/**
* Returns the running value of the active thread.
*/
bool IsRunning()
{
    return this->_isRunning;
}
/**
* Deletes the repository from the mysql queue table. This is
* only called once it has been created.
*/
bool DeleteQueuedRepository(unsigned int id)
{
    char cmd[256];
    sprintf(cmd, "DELETE FROM RepositoryQueue WHERE Id = %d LIMIT 1;", id);
    Query query = this->_con.query(cmd);
    return (query.exec());
}
};
```

I've removed all the other methods as they're not needed...

Basically it's the DeleteQueuedRepository method which isn't working, the GetQueue works fine.

PS: This is on a Linux OS (Ubuntu server)

Many thanks,
Shaun

Comment: If you are using sprintf to format your queries, why not just use the MySQL/C API, instead? One of the main benefits of MySQL++ is that it lets you use operator<< to construct the queries (and it also has a stream modifier that automatically escapes things... by the way, you don't escape enough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MySQL++ doesn't have a free_result method... or does it?

It doesn't need one. When the result object goes out of scope at the end of `GetQueue()`, all memory associated with it is automatically freed.

```
this->_con = Connection(false);
```

Three problems here:

1. When you create the `RepositoryChecker` object, you already have created a `Connection` object. If you need to pass different parameters to its constructor, you'd do that in the initialization list of the `RepositoryChecker` constructor, not in its body. Read your C++ book.

   What you've done here instead is a) create a default `Connection` object, then b) create a different `Connection` object with exceptions turned off, then c) overwrite the first with the second. If that works, it's highly inefficient. MySQL++ `Connection` objects have had problems with their copy ctors in the past, so if you're using an old version of the library, it could explain your problems.
2. You're telling the `Connection` object (and every object it creates, even indirectly, which means pretty much everything in MySQL++) you don't want it to throw exceptions, but then you wrap it in a big `try` block. Pick one.

   I'd suggest using exceptions — the default in MySQL++ — given the way your code is currently structured. If there is a query error way down in `DeleteQueuedRepository()`, there's no way to see what happened because you'd just pass `false` up to the caller, which is ignored because there is no `else` clause on the call. If you do this, log the `e.what()` message in your `catch` block. You're just throwing that information away right now.
3. There are several places where you're using constructs that look more like Python (or perhaps JavaScript) than C++. This makes me wonder if your problem isn't damage caused by some other misuse of C++.

   On this line in particular, you're using the `this` pointer explicitly, for which there is no need in C++. This code does exactly the same thing:

   ```
    _con = Connection(false);
   ```

   Though again, the line should be replaced entirely, using the `RepositoryChecker` ctor initializer list instead.

Moving on...

```
sprintf(cmd, "DELETE FROM RepositoryQueue WHERE Id = %d LIMIT 1;", id);
```

As others have commented, you'd be better off using the `Query` stream interface:

```
Query q = _con.query();
q << "DELETE FROM RepositoryQueue WHERE Id = " << id << " LIMIT 1";
```

This has several advantages:

- Fixes the type safety problem implied by the one who suggested changing your `%d` to `%u`. C++ IOStreams take care of that for you.
- Automatic quoting of data inserted into the stream, if needed. (Which it isn't, in this case.)
- Prevents any possibility of running off the end of the buffer. You could use the nonportable `snprintf()` instead here, but why?

If you're really happy with `printf()`, there's the [template query interface](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/tquery.html) instead.

```
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
```

Have you read the [threads chapter](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/threads.html) in the user manual? You don't get thread safety for free in MySQL++. Your problem could be due to memory corruption.

*Warren Young, MySQL++ Maintainer*

Comment: Thank you Warren for your reply, I've done what you asked and I now get this following exception thrown by the BadQuery exception: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"  I've done some looking into it, and have read that that error is thrown if the connection isn't closed, or i've used method calls in wrong order.

Comment: In your case, it almost certainly means you haven't consumed all the result sets from your stored procedure call. You will get at least two: at least one result set from the stored procedure itself, plus one containing the exit status of the stored procedure call. Study `print_multiple_results()` in the MySQL++ example `examples/multiquery.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "%d" to "%u" in sprintf.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I've used what Warren gave with query << "query" << param;